# Side-by-side (instead of overlapping) error bars

Tags: matlab, plot, overlap, errorbar, matlab-hg2

I have some data and I am plotting the mean at each time point with error bars showing the standard deviation.

I can simply use `errorbar(x, y, err)` and this works fine for a single line. However, if I want to plot multiple data sets in the same plot, the error bars overlap and it looks bad:

[image: error bars overlap and graph makes no sense]

I would like the error bars to be side by side. So each regression is slightly displaced from the previous ones. Is there an easy way to do this that I am overlooking?

Comment: You could offset the `X` values passed to `errorbar` so they do not stack but this would shift the error bars off of your specific points in time. It would be helpful if you provided code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: This is in the new graphics engine rigth?

Comment: If your X axis is categorical than @excaza solution is the most convenient one. Just use something like `s=[-1 1]; offx = x + rand(size(x)).*0.01.*x.*s(randi(2,size(x)))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a known or random offset to the `x` values of your points, e.g.

```
s=[-1 1]; 
offx = x + rand(size(x)).*0.01.*x.*s(randi(2,size(x)))
errorbar(offx, y, err)
```

Alternatively, R2018b introduced the [`stackedplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stackedplot.html) function. It's not what you were asking about (horizontal offset), but it might be useful (vertical offset, like subplot).